# Translate audio from speaker output in python with azureSDK

Tags: python, azure, audio, stream, pyaudio

I'm looking to make an application, who woul'd let me translate any audio going out of the speaker in live stream. This way, i will be able to translate any videoconference from any live stream app(youtube,teams,zoom,etc.). I'm not far from a solution, but not there yet.

Src language would be: `fr-CA` or `en-US`
Dst language would be : `fr-Ca` or `en-US`

I was able to get audio stream back from speaker with a custom version of `pyaudio` allowing loopback with the WASAPI of windows.(https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio)

The next step is to shoot the stream in realtime to Azure translate api in the `speechsdk`.

so far, the part of getting the stream from speakers is working, but when i plug it with azure, i don't have any error, but it doesn't return any result either. In fact, every like 30 second i recive a `reason=ResultReason.NoMatch` or a bribe of text that make no sens.

My first though is that the stream byte coming from speaker witch is 48khz, 2 channels is not supported by Azure stream.(i think i read somewhere on the net that it support only 16khz 1 channel, but i'm not sure). And if that so, i found a way to split split two channel into 1, but i don't know how to drop from 48khz to 16khz from a chunk of bytes in realtime..

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks. Here my code:

```
import time
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
speech_key, service_region = "", "westus"
finalResultSRC = ""
finalResultDst = ""

RATE = 48000
KHz_RATE = int(RATE/1000)
CHUNK = int(RATE)


def translation_continuous():
    """performs continuous speech translation from input from an audio file"""
    # <TranslationContinuous>
    # set up translation parameters: source language and target languages
    translation_config = speechsdk.translation.SpeechTranslationConfig(
        subscription=speech_key, region=service_region,
        speech_recognition_language='fr-CA')

    # setup the audio stream
    audioFormat = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(
        samples_per_second=KHz_RATE, bits_per_sample=16, channels=2)
    stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(audioFormat)

    translation_config.add_target_language("en-US")
    stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream()
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream)

    # Creates a translation recognizer using and audio file as input.
    recognizer = speechsdk.translation.TranslationRecognizer(
        translation_config=translation_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    def result_callback(event_type, evt):
        """callback to display a translation result"""
        # print("{}: {}\n\tTranslations: {}\n\tResult Json: {}".format(
        # event_type, evt, evt.result.translations.items(), evt.result.json))
        print(evt)
        if event_type == "RECOGNIZING":
            # Translate
            print(evt.result.translations.items()[0][1])
            # Original
            # print(type(evt.result.json))

    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that signals to stop continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    # connect callback functions to the events fired by the recognizer
    recognizer.session_started.connect(
        lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.session_stopped.connect(
        lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    # event for intermediate results
    recognizer.recognizing.connect(
        lambda evt: result_callback('RECOGNIZING', evt))
    # event for final result
    recognizer.recognized.connect(
        lambda evt: result_callback('RECOGNIZED', evt))
    # cancellation event
    recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print(
        'CANCELED: {} ({})'.format(evt, evt.reason)))

    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    def synthesis_callback(evt):
        """
        callback for the synthesis event
        """
        print('SYNTHESIZING {}\n\treceived {} bytes of audio. Reason: {}'.format(
            evt, len(evt.result.audio), evt.result.reason))

    # connect callback to the synthesis event
    recognizer.synthesizing.connect(synthesis_callback)

    # start translation
    recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    # start pushing data until all data has been read from the file
    try:
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        pstream = p.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=2, rate=RATE,
            input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=5,
            as_loopback=True
        )
        while(True):
            frame = pstream.read(CHUNK)

            #frames = wav_fh.readframes(n_bytes)
            #print('read {} bytes'.format(len(frames)))
            # if not frames:
            #     print('break')
            #     break
            if frame:
                #ch1 = cutChannelFromStream(frame, 1, 2)
                print('got frame from speakers')
                stream.write(frame)
            time.sleep(1)

    finally:
        # stop recognition and clean up
        stream.close()
        recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()

    print(finalResultSRC)
    # recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
    # </TranslationContinuous>


translation_continuous()
```

Comment: What you need is to _downsample_ the audio. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55209505/6273251) for info on this.

Comment: This looks quite relevant too: https://github.com/tuxu/python-samplerate/issues/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm gonna try those solutions!

Comment: Did you ever get this translation project working? I'm looking for exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution. I had  indeed to downsample to 16000hz and use mono channel. I base my code on this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30660779/11633069), but using stream chunk rather than read from file.

My function was:

```
def downsampleFrames(data, inrate=48000, outrate=16000, inchannels=2, outchannels=1):
    try:
        converted = audioop.ratecv(data, 2, inchannels, inrate, outrate, None)
        if outchannels == 1:
            converted = audioop.tomono(converted[0], 2, 1, 0)
    except:
        print('Failed to downsample')
        return False

    return converted
```

and from pyaudio, i send a chunk of data like this :

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        pstream = p.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=2, rate=RATE,
            input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
            input_device_index=5,
            as_loopback=True
        )
        while(True):
            frame = pstream.read(CHUNK)
            if frame:
                downFrame = downsampleFrames(frame)
                stream.write(downFrame)
```

Comment: When i am trying your code module, i am getting Session started, session stopped and closing session messages on CMD. can you please let me know is there anything specific i need to do to run this code?